# Is it possible to change an NSOpenPanel's prompt based on a modifier key

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, swift, appstore-sandbox

I tried making an `NSOpenPanel` subclass that allows the `prompt` (Open button title) to change as the user held down the Option key, like so:

```
class CustomOpenPanel: NSOpenPanel {

    var standardPrompt: String?
    var alternatePrompt: String?

    override func flagsChanged(theEvent: NSEvent) {
        super.flagsChanged(theEvent)

        if standardPrompt == nil && alternatePrompt == nil {
            return;
        }

        let optionKeyDown = (theEvent.modifierFlags & .AlternateKeyMask) != nil

        self.prompt = optionKeyDown ? alternatePrompt : standardPrompt
    }

}
```

But when I created an instance (like so):

```c
CustomOpenPanel *openPanel = [CustomOpenPanel openPanel];
```

I get this message:

> AppDomain.CustomOpenPanel is not a supported subclass for sandboxing

I would like to add this functionality to my app, and am open to other ways of achieving this, but haven't seen any that would work.

1. Is there a way to make my class "supported for sandboxing"?
2. Is there another way to accomplish the goal of toggling the `prompt` property as a modifier key is held down?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, not want you want to hear:

1. No. You cannot subclass, or add category to, the standard file panels under sandboxing.
2. Customisation is limited to the properties you can set before running the panels and what you can achieve via the delegate.

You *might* find a way to do it, I hesitate to suggest anything as playing with the file panels under sandboxing is a route to madness, but the chance of it being robust is low.

So think of another approach to satisfy your needs without touching the file panel.

Comment: You're right, not what I want to hear :-( ... I was going to look at potentially swizzling the `flagsChanged` method next

Comment: If you check the class hierarchy at *runtime* when under the sandbox you'll find `NSOpenPanel` isn't what the documentation says the normal hierarchy is, rather its `NSRemoteOpenPanel` -> `NSRemoteSavePanel` -> `NSObject` and `respondsToSelector:` for `flagsChanged:` returns `NO`...